# TypeScript Interface and Generics for function parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to create multiple tests and I want to ensure the setup is strongly typed.I was reading through the Generics documentation and I can understand the simple cases but I get lost with the advanced examples.

I tried doing something similar to what's described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the last example.

There are two test function signatures that varies depending on the tested value and the condition value:

```
interface ITestFuncWithCond<ValueType, ConditionType> {
   (value: ValueType, condition: ConditionType): boolean;
};

interface ITestFuncNoCond<ValueType> {
   (value: ValueType): boolean;
};
```

The idea is to do something like this with the tests (note the types):

```
// Example A
// No condition param
const testA: Tester = createTest(StringTestIsEmpty);
// Value param type must be string.
testA.test("myString");

// Example B
// condition param is number
const testB: Tester = createTest(StringLengthEquals, 2);
// Value param type must be string.
testB.test("myString");

// Example C
// condition param is string
const testC: Tester = createTest(StringEquals, "myString");
// Value param type must be string.
testC.test("myString");

// Example D
// condition param is number
const testD: Tester = createTest(NumberEquals, 10);
// Value param type must be number.
testD.test(5);
```

And this is the pseudo code that I have for this, but as you can probably see, I need some guiding words to untangle this.

I updated the below code to try to better explain what I'm looking for.
[Here's a sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9GAEAqCmDOAXSBLAtgBwDazbAdogIaIoD2%208oAxhUpAPoDKiATivgOZxICS8AUUyIAnpAC8kABQAPAFyQk7LgEoFAIzJkcRfBIB8kAN6hIkWpW2wAdFjKdZKgNynIrWIgCurPTInjJACJAlxAAXxo6ZGY2Dk4AGQJORAALAQBHTyIseAlpeUVYrgAaSCwFfE80dVhWNUhNK10DY1cLeCtbe1lSrGdXdy8fSBlbJNT-SSxQiJB26JZlTgysnLzZBSU40pFNos56xp09cUMTEDN2zrsHGR3%20i7cPb19JyBEZyMpogDkqmtYK2yuUkG0glWqtR2FX%20tUOWmOLXOlzo126d3eDzMgxeIzeH1As1AEEgABEUAAzCm1AjIRAIRC5IgANyIKCwRHUOFABCqMAZPyIeFaj0WcR4iH4QgwomKrjFXESXFSQJyctF%201V8HVZj%20kMBmWBhNAxKgEsUKE4%20BI3gQ1lAHHprApRGosEgvAlADFPPhqAB1FCpADCFAAJgAeABq2U8sGgIgwsFKofwYaD5HwCaTZ1cUlZWDjChjhfjieT5nDGYoClT6dIFGzsHhTXwM1CDsItRdbo93t91B%20ZDr0djZZzIrM%20bHxbHTZbx3bJrmHPguQltQjderWfLpRLcabuce1rwCglgrwoRRaZ3AH5a1WG7uk9fICSD%20PYHef5Bt8%20m0gH871cDB2FZelIHpJAfT9Z8FE9BlYIDIMUhHT8mxTJ9MyPSAAB8%20yQgch3Qudy30ZczBJc15lYTxqEQMhWEgAB3VDIHTKkaUIC0rRtdx4HtR5aPoxjWCkaDEEvWBzwFIVmzfESGKYiS5LPfkkGk0oLHrTNH1vADyyxStvjo5TxMk6TZM0%20TtOwigHz-eyX2bSczCglIUEE093UkSz5LfMxUi86wdJ3PIwufQL3ygAAJGlSlSd1-OFLzIE8eBYDDKCyEgalEGoFIPPdV0vGyKCGTygdn2kSTeEwPpXCCzzBMk5Car8lrrE4Dx2szVSbLwFRKMgIlHg-Mik0UFIyE8LBspqQoljypiKvoABBUoACFIF0bLg1KPbptm%20aGndCEARW5jJLJISqKgQJgsEyLM0CY65oW91fTDWAKQ4LLUD0G71rumLIEerqXooN74Bmj6zvBi7aiutbkB2o7SUOtNwa2Lg3opVbJODUHJOnUtZ1LecNARWBmmRdzKVqyHnJUNz3KeIYga6trqv6gs40S5mDMzYyzDCSBYByd16fZnFhie6webgvmx1F0bXDGswwJQCD3Xywr%202VihoxTCWZHpNNcgAbQAXXwyArah-AFF0EQbf0KQUEN6gFDJotICjUprGDp2AFkiBEGpa1Z04Ghp3Qg5D5zw8jmS-1ZmWOdxTOgoZX3mWLGPDC9oi-XzRPQuTiOamGx4xY1kbtd1yAesQPqKAGqT5OsruhrZxQ2IKorO%20kjOmvc6giEyjTe5sBVuAZKVhF2fvZeeeWuv1lJvefKQYiWCUl5lEQ1fruuJ6n90L3k6x56VZI0kNHIFBz9y5a5kKt53-r97ie%20VSftqDyIUnan3VufS4l8Z7SVvpqQBL9x5r05sAwSX9S4MR-vPLUgsQEs2imfdmkDp7XzwNYPUAItQIIgW-deH9UEeANug3eDByG1GwSgyuwsKBgNmOzXh4CxoUl5hQcw7gSDxgZCPbu0DbImV0g5F2%20AT492RvTEkmVkCeAwDlSAYEyBJlYFgMQW9ipuEtCkOkDIBi0PBLAFiM9ahSLwHZLh%20AHhjRJAIGQQpsDunWqaSAQ45HhQwEQVgQoAlhgoAAcmQLofAZBiCQQ3MxGok8MruiDJANAGVkCLR6vgWoKBqBfHoJJdaEUxH0glFIEhc99iH0EMvB4E1Sy6LCUKKC5Zsm5IRrjTgQlymK0kYENAIh56BAeAErxPicCQC2gEp27TwloFQLkJGrBSmWKQDtSQ1AqkSKQLUtS9Slj-0fqsIBAAmFpUBPzLM6aIKaOT6CLX6YMhkW1hlHNGeM-YkyOzgCgDMhq7pgyLOcg81ZaV%20lbNRsGSptNqmSLqbApY7DfkTNuQHMcUKunPN6W8-YHykDE1Jpi-5UygWQBBb4skELXF4rShsuFklSSIvETU1FrCDSXNKAARgAAzYvuaElZ%20L3QvLyedWErASWIFJN8xAUgACszggA)

```
// Test implementations
const _StringTestIsEmpty = (x: string): boolean => {
  console.log(x);
  return x === "";
}
const _StringLengthEquals = (x: string, l: number): boolean => {
  console.log(x, l);
  return x.length === l;
}
const _StringEquals = (x: string, y: string): boolean => {
  console.log(x, y);
  return x === y;
}
const _NumberEquals = (x: number, y: number): boolean => {
  console.log(x, y);
  return x === y;
}

// Different tests available
enum TestName {
  StringTestIsEmpty,
  StringLengthEquals,
  StringEquals,
  NumberEquals
}

// Test signatures.
interface ITestFuncWithCond<ValueType, ConditionType> {
  (value: ValueType, condition: ConditionType): boolean;
};

interface ITestFuncNoCond<ValueType> {
  (value: ValueType): boolean;
};

class Tester<ConditionType, ValueType> {
  name: TestName;
  condition?: ConditionType;
  // ValueType??? ConditionType ???
  private testFunction: ITestFuncWithCond<ValueType, ConditionType> | ITestFuncNoCond<ValueType>

  // Test constructor with different signatures.
  constructor(testName: TestName);
  constructor(testName: TestName, condition: ConditionType);
  constructor(testName: TestName, condition?: ConditionType) {
    this.name = testName;
    this.condition = condition;
    // Here, the testName is used to fetch the actual test function (testImpl)
    this.testFunction = this.getFunction(testName)

  }

  // ValueType should be string for test A, B and C, and should be number for test D.
  // "this.condition" should be undefined in test A.
  // "this.condition" should be "number for test B and D, and "string" for testC.
  test(value: ValueType): boolean {
    if (this.condition) {
      return this.testFunction(value, this.condition);
    } else {
      return this.testFunction(value);
    }
  }

  private fetchTestFunction<V, C extends [] | [condition: any]>(iTestFunc: (value: V, ...conditionMaybe: C) => boolean, ...conditionMaybe: C) {
    return {
      test: (v: V) => iTestFunc(v, ...conditionMaybe)
    }
  }

  private getFunction(testName: TestName) {
    switch (testName) {
      case TestName.StringTestIsEmpty: {
        return this.fetchTestFunction(_StringTestIsEmpty);
      }
      case TestName.StringLengthEquals: {
        return this.fetchTestFunction(_StringLengthEquals, this.condition);
      }
      case TestName.StringEquals: {
        return this.fetchTestFunction(_StringEquals, this.condition);
      }
      case TestName.NumberEquals: {
        return this.fetchTestFunction(_NumberEquals, this.condition);
      }
    }
  }
}

function createTest(testName: TestName, condition?: any): Tester {
  // set up to properly fetch the right test
  return new Tester(testName, condition);
}

// Example A
// No condition param
// don't annotate Tester because it must be generic
const testA = createTest(TestName.StringTestIsEmpty);
// Value param type must be string.
testA.test("myString");

// Example B
// condition param is number
const testB = createTest(TestName.StringLengthEquals, 2);
// Value param type must be string.
testB.test("myString");

// Example C
// condition param is string
const testC = createTest(TestName.StringEquals, "myString");
// Value param type must be string.
testC.test("myString");

// Example D
// condition param is number
const testD = createTest(TestName.NumberEquals, 10);
// Value param type must be number.
testD.test(5);
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand exactly what your goal is. What are `StringLengthEquals` and `StringTestIsEmpty`, types or functions? Can you create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem in a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?

Comment: It helps to trim question code down to a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play). The static type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) so there's no runtime test like "if the type parameter is `C`" you can perform.  Maybe you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/YmpLXm)?  But it's hard to tell without a nice clear example.

Comment: Thanks AlexWayne and Jcalz for taking your time to look at this. @jcalz The example you show is actually pretty close to what I'm looking for. Only the test needs additional information, like the test name and a typed condition value.

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/zwOREW)?  I don't see why you *need* the test to be an enum as opposed to a function, since you can always just use my previous code along with an object whose keys are enums and values are the functions (like the `Tests` in the code I've linked here).